# Yii framework CDBCommand errors

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I have this error and I am new to yii framework. It was working fine on another server after moving to a new server, I just replaced my database and my framework; I didn't change anything! This is the error I get:

```
CDbException

CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'geolocationDetails' doesn't have a default value. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `hts_users` (`mobile_status`, `name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `userstatus`, `activationStatus`, `createdDate`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7)

/var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(358)

346         {
347             if($this->_connection->enableProfiling)
348                 Yii::endProfile('system.db.CDbCommand.execute('.$this->getText().$par.')','system.db.CDbCommand.execute');
349 
350             $errorInfo=$e instanceof PDOException ? $e->errorInfo : null;
351             $message=$e->getMessage();
352             Yii::log(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand::execute() failed: {error}. The SQL statement executed was: {sql}.',
353                 array('{error}'=>$message, '{sql}'=>$this->getText().$par)),CLogger::LEVEL_ERROR,'system.db.CDbCommand');
354 
355             if(YII_DEBUG)
356                 $message.='. The SQL statement executed was: '.$this->getText().$par;
357 
358             throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: {error}',
359                 array('{error}'=>$message)),(int)$e->getCode(),$errorInfo);
360         }
361     }
362 
363     /**
364      * Executes the SQL statement and returns query result.
365      * This method is for executing an SQL query that returns result set.
366      * @param array $params input parameters (name=>value) for the SQL execution. This is an alternative
367      * to {@link bindParam} and {@link bindValue}. If you have multiple input parameters, passing
368      * them in this way can improve the performance. Note that if you pass parameters in this way,
369      * you cannot bind parameters or values using {@link bindParam} or {@link bindValue}, and vice versa.
370      * Please also note that all values are treated as strings in this case, if you need them to be handled as
Stack Trace
#0  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(1080): CDbCommand->execute()
1075         {
1076             Yii::trace(get_class($this).'.insert()','system.db.ar.CActiveRecord');
1077             $builder=$this->getCommandBuilder();
1078             $table=$this->getTableSchema();
1079             $command=$builder->createInsertCommand($table,$this->getAttributes($attributes));
1080             if($command->execute())
1081             {
1082                 $primaryKey=$table->primaryKey;
1083                 if($table->sequenceName!==null)
1084                 {
1085                     if(is_string($primaryKey) && $this->$primaryKey===null)
#1  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(809): CActiveRecord->insert(null)
804      * @return boolean whether the saving succeeds
805      */
806     public function save($runValidation=true,$attributes=null)
807     {
808         if(!$runValidation || $this->validate($attributes))
809             return $this->getIsNewRecord() ? $this->insert($attributes) : $this->update($attributes);
810         else
811             return false;
812     }
813 
814     /**
#2  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/protected/modules/admin/controllers/UserController.php(67): CActiveRecord->save(false)
62             $password = $_POST['Users']['password'];
63             $model->userstatus = 1;
64             $model->activationStatus = 1;
65             if($model->validate()) {
66                 $model->password = base64_encode($password);
67                 $model->save(false);
68                 $siteSettings = Sitesettings::model()->find();
69                 $mail = new YiiMailer();
70                 if($siteSettings->smtpEnable == 1) {
71                     //$mail->IsSMTP();                         // Set mailer to use SMTP
72                     $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';                         // Set mailer to use SMTP
#3  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): UserController->actionCreate()
44         $controller=$this->getController();
45         $method=new ReflectionMethod($controller, $methodName);
46         if($method->getNumberOfParameters()>0)
47             return $this->runWithParamsInternal($controller, $method, $params);
48 
49         $controller->$methodName();
50         return true;
51     }
52 }
#4  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array())
303     {
304         $priorAction=$this->_action;
305         $this->_action=$action;
306         if($this->beforeAction($action))
307         {
308             if($action->runWithParams($this->getActionParams())===false)
309                 $this->invalidActionParams($action);
310             else
311                 $this->afterAction($action);
312         }
313         $this->_action=$priorAction;
#5  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(133): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
128             $filter=$this->itemAt($this->filterIndex++);
129             Yii::trace('Running filter '.($filter instanceof CInlineFilter ? get_class($this->controller).'.filter'.$filter->name.'()':get_class($filter).'.filter()'),'system.web.filters.CFilterChain');
130             $filter->filter($this);
131         }
132         else
133             $this->controller->runAction($this->action);
134     }
135 }
#6  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
286             $this->runAction($action);
287         else
288         {
289             $priorAction=$this->_action;
290             $this->_action=$action;
291             CFilterChain::create($this,$action,$filters)->run();
292             $this->_action=$priorAction;
293         }
294     }
295 
296     /**
#7  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array("postOnly + delete"))
260         {
261             if(($parent=$this->getModule())===null)
262                 $parent=Yii::app();
263             if($parent->beforeControllerAction($this,$action))
264             {
265                 $this->runActionWithFilters($action,$this->filters());
266                 $parent->afterControllerAction($this,$action);
267             }
268         }
269         else
270             $this->missingAction($actionID);
#8  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("create")
277         {
278             list($controller,$actionID)=$ca;
279             $oldController=$this->_controller;
280             $this->_controller=$controller;
281             $controller->init();
282             $controller->run($actionID);
283             $this->_controller=$oldController;
284         }
285         else
286             throw new CHttpException(404,Yii::t('yii','Unable to resolve the request "{route}".',
287                 array('{route}'=>$route===''?$this->defaultController:$route)));
#9  
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("admin/user/create")
136             foreach(array_splice($this->catchAllRequest,1) as $name=>$value)
137                 $_GET[$name]=$value;
138         }
139         else
140             $route=$this->getUrlManager()->parseUrl($this->getRequest());
141         $this->runController($route);
142     }
143 
144     /**
145      * Registers the core application components.
146      * This method overrides the parent implementation by registering additional core components.
#10 
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/framework/base/CApplication.php(184): CWebApplication->processRequest()
179     public function run()
180     {
181         if($this->hasEventHandler('onBeginRequest'))
182             $this->onBeginRequest(new CEvent($this));
183         register_shutdown_function(array($this,'end'),0,false);
184         $this->processRequest();
185         if($this->hasEventHandler('onEndRequest'))
186             $this->onEndRequest(new CEvent($this));
187     }
188 
189     /**
#11 
–  /var/www/domain/public_html/folder/index.php(13): CApplication->run()
08 defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
09 // specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
10 defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
11 
12 require_once($yii);
13 Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
2016-12-16 16:27:08 Apache Yii Framework/1.1.16-dev
```

This is the whole error that i get If i miss something or you want me to past anything let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: you are trying to insert a row  with null value for column that not  admit null

Comment: @scaisEdge it was working fine on another server after moving to a new server i just replaced my database and my framework i didn't change anything !!

Comment: *I didn't change anything...* - except the server, and database?

Comment: @gravity moved the database to the new server too

Comment: Your error is `Command failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'geolocationDetails' doesn't have a default value.`  Have you validated that your database server has the *exact same configuration* as your old one?  It sounds like your table field configurations are likely different.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved it was the mysql configuration i added this
sql_mode=IGNORE_SPACE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
Thanks everyone who helps use on stackoverflow much appreciated
Thanks To @Gravity